# Python code to run for next 100 days from today

Tags: python, python-3.x, linecache

I want to run below line of code for 200 days from today. 
Suppose today is 1st days so my code is-

```
line = linecache.getline("lines1.txt",1)
print(line)
```

Suppose today is 2nd days so my code is-

```
line = linecache.getline("lines1.txt",2)
print(line)
```

Suppose today is 3rd days so my code becomes-

```
line = linecache.getline("lines1.txt",3)
print(line)
```

I want above 1,2,3,4,5......200 to be calculated everyday. I don't want a loop to run for 200 days.

I just need to get 1,2,3,4,5......200 count from python Date system or any other counting system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a marker date then calculated difference between today dan marker date

```
(datetime.datetime(2016,9,2) - datetime.datetime(2016,9,1) ).days
output:
1
```

Comment: >>> (datetime.datetime(2017,2,1) - datetime.datetime(2016,9,1)).days
153

Comment: With this I can get the difference but how datetime.datetime(2016,9,2) will become datetime.datetime(2016,9,3), datetime.datetime(2016,9,4), datetime.datetime(2016,9,5)..... datetime.datetime(2016,12,8) automatically till 100 days.

Comment: @VishalMahajan  datetime.datetime.today()